# onFormSubmit and timer program install for add-on

Tags: google-apps-script

I am working to get a timed script and an onFormSubmit script installed in an add-on. I cannot seem to get them working. It's not something which I can test without publishing. Every-time I publish it takes days to weeks to be able to move ahead. Any and all help would be appreciated on the below.

```
function createTimeDrivenTriggers() {
  var p = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
  var t = p.getProperty("timetrigger");
  var authInfo =ScriptApp.getAuthorizationInfo(ScriptApp.AuthMode.FULL);
  // Loop over all triggers.
  var allTriggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  for (var i = 0; i < allTriggers.length; i++) {
    // If the current trigger is the correct one, delete it.
    if (allTriggers[i].getUniqueId() == t) {
      ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(allTriggers[i]);
      break;
    }
  }
  var trig = ScriptApp.newTrigger('checkAllInviteStatus').timeBased().everyHours(1).create();
   p.setProperty("timetrigger", trig.getUniqueId());
}

function createFormSubmitTrigger(e){
  var p = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
  var form = FormApp.openById(e);
  var authInfo = ScriptApp.getAuthorizationInfo(ScriptApp.AuthMode.FULL);
  var t = ScriptApp.newTrigger('checkAllInviteStatus').forForm(form).onFormSubmit().create();
  p.setProperty("form"+e, t.getUniqueId());
}

function openSidebar() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Page').setTitle('AutoInvite').setWidth(370);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
  createTimeDrivenTriggers();
}

function formcreate(dateTime){
    var form = FormApp.create(dateTime.EventTitle);

    dateTime.EditFormID = form.getEditUrl();

    dateTime.PublishFormID= form.getPublishedUrl();
    var item = form.addTextItem();
    item.setTitle(dateTime.EmailItem);

    form.setDestination(FormApp.DestinationType.SPREADSHEET, sheetid);
    form.setDescription(dateTime.Description);  
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();

    //Attach the form responses to the spreadsheet
    var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
    sheets[0].setName(dateTime.EventTitle + ' Responses')
    var f = form.getId();
    createFormSubmitTrigger(f);
}
```

Comment: You need to have a development version of your add-on and publish it unlisted so that you don't need to wait for approval.  You may need to wait a few minutes for the unlisted add-on to become available.  So, copy your apps script file, and use the copy as the development version.  You should be using a stand alone apps script file to publish an add-on.

Comment: Great advice. Thank you.

Comment: Part of your problem, is that you are using `ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers()` to get existing triggers, `allTriggers `.  That won't work.  You must get the Form, and get all user triggers using the Form.  Unfortunately, the logic of how the triggers are categorized is a little confusing.  `ownerFrm = FormApp.getActiveForm(); allTriggers = ScriptApp.getUserTriggers(ownerFrm);//Get all installed Form triggers`  You'd think that `var allTrgrs = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();` would do what the documentation says it will do, but for an add-on it won't.  The add-on project is owned by you.

Comment: Not the add-on user.  So, it won't get all the triggers of the user who installed the add-on.